# Match 2 Excel columns and add value to another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following excel sheet

I need to compare (match) Col 1 with Col 2
I need to add to Col 3 quantity amount to column 4
if Col 3 is more then Col 4 it will just add to the current amount of Col 4 if Col 3 is less then Col 4 it must just ignore updating col 4

[image: Example]

RN123 = RN123
Add quantity value of Col 3 to Col4 which will be 7

Any suggestion of the structure of formula to use ?
Or resources to view ?

```
=SUM(IF(A2:A7=B2:B7,1,0),C2 + I2)
```

Comment: Unless the value in column 4 already is from a formula, you can't keep its value stored while typing in a new formula. You could however, achieve this with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible because in order to update the column you need to reference it in the formula.

Not sure if you have to have column 4 update but if you create a separate column to do the check/update in then you can do the below.

So, what I have would be a similar formula to what you have but I just added an else that will return the value of column 4 if it is bigger than 3 as it should be ignored in that case. Adding the below in case my screenshots don't show.

=IF(AND(O3=P3;Q3>R3);Q3+R3;R3)

1. O3 and P3 are the two Prod id columns.
2. Q3 and R3 would be column 3 and 4 respectively.

Hope it helps.